# DEM generation using Agisoft Metashape Professional

Tags: aerial-photography, photogrammetry, agisoft-photoscan

Currently, I am processing Aerial photographs acquired in 1967 and 1984 (all are acquired by frame camera) using Agisoft Metashape Professional software. What I faced is; the DEM generated from 1967 Aerial photography is negative (from around -37,200 meter to -11,600 meter). The DEM generated from the 1984 Aerial photography is correct.  FYI, I did the same steps to process for the 1967 and 1984 aerial photographs.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using ground control points with known altitudes to ensure your surface conforms to  actual altitudes?  Before building the point cloud did you uncheck all of the images in the Camera pane and check all the ground control points in the Markers pane?   Also, can you use something like ExifTools and post the results from one of your images/